# ViewDidAppear never gets called for iPad 1 or iPhone 3G devices

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

Any idea why this is happening? I'm setting breakpoints on the method and they never get called.

This does not happen on my iPhone 4S however. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried an NSLog() instead of breakpoints?  They aren't the best for testing.

Comment: It's a simple -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { NSLog(@"Hi VIEW");}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an iOS 5 issue. Before iOS 5 viewDidAppear did not automatically get called on nested viewControllers.  After iOS 5 it is. You may need to put a check in your code for the OS version and manually call viewDidAppear.